# backstretch image overlapping navigation

Tags: css, image

How can I get the navigation to appear in front of the backstretched image? As soon as it loads it appears over the navigation which pretty much becomes un-clickable/unseen at that point.

Comment: You'd have to provide significantly more information than that if we are to have any chance of helping you. Your current code, a link to an example, what you've already tried, etc... [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the image behind the rest of the page content.

```
#backstretch {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

in your CSS should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks so much! I kinda figured it had something to do with the z-index but wasn't sure what to do as I'm new to css and didn't see any backstretch fields in the main css file. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Ok so it works on the pc just fine, but on my mobile phone it still disappears, is there a different parameter to be set for mobile devices?

Comment: Different browsers will unfortunately quite possibly behave differently - try playing with the z-index of other elements as well (e.g. increasing it for `#wrapper`)

Comment: I had to increase the z-index of other elements drastically. The backstretch has the default z-index of `-999998`. Some elements I had to give the same z-index, be it postive (`999998`) in order to make them appear. Some required an even _higher_ z-index than that.
The backstretch plugin may cause some minor discomforts indeed when it comes to layers.